# Trying to save dynamically to database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to save the client's original file name into my storage and into the database.  I can save it into the storage fine.  I have been having an extremely difficult time trying to get this into my database properly.  I don't know how to fix the 2nd to last line of code so the foreach loop works properly.

```php
$files = array();
$files = $request->allFiles();
$folder = $id;
if (count($files) > 0) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //if files should be stored in public drive, change 'local' to 'public'

        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($folder, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $plansubmission-> current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1 = $filename;
        $plansubmission->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably don't want to be updating the same field on the same model every time through the loop

Comment: Yeah I am trying to change the 'current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1' to something dynamic but don't know how.  I have an array of files.  I need to get the name of the column that is in my validation for the given file

Comment: do some debugging, see if the array returned from `allFiles` is an associative array keyed by input name, if so then you know what file you are currently saving in each iteration ... you will want to move the $plansubmission->save()` outside the loop

Comment: Yes, I did dd and it returns the proper file.  

I thought this would be a common thing in Laravel.  So difficult.  What I am trying to do is have the user upload a file, then have that go to my storage, then save the original filename in my datase so I can create a route to that file.  But, it seems all that can be done is save the server path and pull the files manually off the server

Comment: yes file uploads are common and done all the time

Comment: yeah i got the file upload part.  but how would you display that back to the user?  for instance, if someone has a CRM where users can upload their files for storage and then go in and see them.  that seems impossible in Laravel

Comment: its not impossible at all, this is done all the time, there is nothing special about what you are doing at all ... what do you need, just a filename or part of a path, what do you want to store in the database?

Comment: yes, but it won't let me save the proper name to my database because i can't create a way to dynamically save this (see 2nd to last line of code).  Therefore, its impossible to display the proper file to the user

Comment: does the input name match the field in the database you want to save this path to? ... it seems you are having issues with loops

Comment: yes, it does.  i think i do have an issue with loops.  if this were updating one file, it would be easy.  I wouldn't be using the loop.  i would simply request the file, save it to storage, and then update the file name.  but, there are multiple files that can be uploaded in the form.  so, i need to update the name of the proper column in the database for each file to the original file name.  does that make sense?

Comment: right now, it is hard coded so it will just keep updating that one column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `allFiles` is giving you an associative array with the input names as the keys and your database field matches these field names, you can just iterate this array and use the key for the attribute name on the model:

```
foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($folder, $file, $filename);
    $plansubmission->$name = $filename;
}

$plansubmission->save();
```

It might be wise to make sure the input name is one of the 3 that you are expecting so that you are only setting a field that actually exists as a field on the table and not some random name (if a user was to alter the form in some way).

Comment: thanks, yes i'm working on figuring that part out now and also how to name the file with a timestamp so it doesn't overwrite a file with the same name

Comment: `putFile` will generate a filename with a random 40 character name if you prefer https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#storing-files